# c#.net remote powershell for iis

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, iis

Hi I have the following bit of code

```
 //set up exchange server name
        var Exchangesrv = "ex1.iah.ac.uk";


        // Initialize PowerShell engine
        var shell = PowerShell.Create();

        // Add the script to the PowerShell object
        shell.Commands.AddScript("Invoke-Command -Computername hostname.example.com -ScriptBlock{get-alias}");

        // Execute the script
        var results = shell.Invoke();


        Input.DataSource = results;
        Input.DataBind();
```

So very simply I want to invoke a power shell command and the "input" is a list box object I am populating

But When i run it on the IIS server it does not work, I think it is because the IIS application is not running with an account that is admin on the remote server I am trying to run the command against. Can any one help resolving this. How can I get the webpage to call this invoke command with the right credentials?

**Edit**
So i decided to create a profile on the web server that means when the account that I am using opens power-shell the exchange module is loaded. But I don't see this loading when using the following code

```
using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            //powershell.Runspace = runspace;


            // Add the script to the PowerShell object
            //powershell.AddScript("Get-alias");
            powershell.AddScript("Get-DynamicDistributionGroup");


            // Execute the script
            var results = powershell.Invoke();


            Input.DataSource = results;
            Input.DataBind();
```

So What should be happening is power shell runs locally on the web server, but i need it to load the profile however I cant see why it is not doing it. Is there a command to force it to load the moduel.

Comment: Well, first things first - get proper logging in there so you know *why* it's failing, rather than just assuming. Secondly, if it is because of insufficient privileges (which is likely to be one issue, I agree), then you can [impersonate as a different user](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=impersonation+iis+asp.net&oq=impersonation+iis+asp.net&aqs=chrome..69i57.4032j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for just that section of code. Alternatively, the `Invoke-Command` has a `-Credential` parameter that could also be used for for impersonation.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I have turned on logging in IIS but I don't see anything in the log files about it.

Comment: Sorry - I meant you should add logging messages to your *application*, typically by using a library like `Log4Net`, to ensure that you can accurately diagnose this and future problems. IIS logging is designed to tell you about the HTTP call, not the application processing.

Comment: Hi, this seems to be an issue loading the exchange power shell snap in remotely as it just keeps telling me it does not exist.

Comment: I think i need this "New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft. Exchange" but I dont know how I included that in my code

Answer (score 1):

The property on the application pool is "Load User Profile". This must be set to True.

I can't tell anyone why this is, but it solved my Access denied issue.

More about the property here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity/

Answer (score 0):

In the end the impersonating and invoking did not do the trick (I could have used invoke but I did not want credentials in the code)

I found I had to change the properties on the application pool and then it worked fine.

Comment: Change them to what?